# Automatically restarting bitcoind five minutes after reboot on ubuntu

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, ubuntu

How can I run bitcoind automatically five minutes after restart?

So far I have crontab set up to reboot my computer every morning at 4AM (it runs into issues when it stays on for more than a couple days). I also have tried to use crontab to restart bitcoind on @reboot, but haven't had any success with that.

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.10, and bitcoind v0.18.0.0. 
Here is my current crontab:

```
0 4 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r +5
@reboot /usr/bin/bitcoind -daemon -conf=/home/<username>/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

Comment: Don't you mean `@reboot /path/to/bitcoind -daemon ...`?  You left out the command name.

Comment: If you want to wait five minutes, you can do `@reboot sleep 5m ; /path/to/bitcoind -daemon ...`

Comment: Fixed to reflect actual crontab. I think I've diagnosed the problem: looking at debug.log, bitcoind can't start an http server on reboot because when my computer shuts down, it doesn't kill the original bitcoind process. As a result, when I start up, bitcoind doesn't have access to port 8332. As a result, I added the following to the first crontab entry: `0 4 * * * bitcoin-cli stop; /sbin/shutdown -r +5`
I added the `sleep 5m`. Appears to do the job.

Comment: If you just need it to shut down and start as your computer reboots, why not use the systemd service?

Comment: @Marty When the computer shuts down the original bitcoind process does get killed. There's something else causing the issue. You may want to look at the `at` command and trigger it at startup. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146615/run-at-command-in-two-minutes-time